# set file permissions in java in stat.mod format

Tags: java

I tried to set file/dir permission like this

> Files.setPosixFilePermissions(
>               path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString(String.valueOf(mode)));

Here mode is `16895` which is a `File:stat:mode`.

Setting like this gives me this exception:

> Invalid mode  at
>   java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions.fromString(PosixFilePermissions.java:128)

How do I solve this..
Any way to set mode of type `file:stat:mode` ??

Help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re using the .fromString methods it will only accept String representing the permissions.

Therefore, in your case, 16895 (base10) converted to base8 is 40777, and converting that would be: r-- --- rwx rwx rwx

So your code should look something like this:

```
Files.setPosixFilePermissions( path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString(“r-- --- rwx rwx rwx”));
```

You can follow these documentation for more [explanations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermissions.html) [and](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-3321/secfile-14/index.html) [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.nio.file.Files&method=setPosixFilePermissions).